# Go dividing massive numbers (big.Int)

Tags: go

I'm trying to divide two massive numbers (e.g. trying to divide 50! by 18!) and I have two big.Int variables set.

```
first.MulRange(1,50)

second.MulRange(1,18)
```

How can I divide the numbers (ideally with integer division)?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to use   "math/big" package ?

Comment: @MIkCode Considering the OP mentions `big.Int`, it seems obvious they are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can I divide the numbers

By invoking [Div()](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Div) method of `Int` (in this case) data type. ("math/big" package)

```
first := new(big.Int).MulRange(1, 50)
second := new(big.Int).MulRange(1, 18)

fmt.Printf("First: %s \n", first.String())
fmt.Printf("Second: %s \n", second.String())
// division
dv := new(big.Int).Div(first, second)

fmt.Printf("Division result: %s \n", dv.String())
```

The result:

```
First: 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
Second: 6402373705728000
Division result: 4750440164794325701367714688167999176704000000000
```